# 2005 Mercury montago

Tags: car

I replaced the back passenger side brake rotor and caliper today and added more brake fluid and pumped the brakes but I still have to push the pedal all the way to the floor before it starts to stop. What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure you bled the brakes correctly? If the pedal goes hard at the bottom of the stroke then there may still be more air in there.

Comment: That’s exactly what it was. I needed to bleed the breaks. Thank you very much.